# Count(*) the total unique entries but for 2 different fields

Tags: sql-server, syntax, count

I'm working on an old table using SQL Server 2005.  (The table isn't designed very well,
but it can't be changed now.)

I'm trying to count the unique entries in 2 columns.

This gives the list I need:

```
SELECT Name1 FROM MyTable UNION SELECT Name2 FROM MyTable -- automatically removes dups
```

But how would I count that?  (Hopefully with 1 statement.)  Something like this, but the
syntax isn't right:

```
SELECT COUNT(SELECT Name1 FROM MyTable UNION SELECT Name2 FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(u.name) FROM (SELECT Name1 name FROM MyTable UNION SELECT Name2 name FROM MyTable) u` - untested

Comment: Why not just use `select distinct name1,name2 from mytable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT Name1 FROM MyTable UNION SELECT Name2 FROM MyTable) AS u

Comment: COUNT(*) will include `NULL` values.  Not sure OP wants that.